# async task with useReducer that is not a hook in react

Tags: reactjs

I am really struggling to understand why there are so many use**Async hook libraries in react when hooks cannot be used in event handlers.

If I look at [this code](https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-async/blob/master/src/use-async-task.js):

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = {
  started: false,
  pending: true,
  error: null,
  result: null,
  start: null,
  abort: null,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'init':
      return initialState;
    case 'ready':
      return {
        ...state,
        start: action.start,
        abort: action.abort,
      };
    case 'start':
      if (state.started) return state; // to bail out just in case
      return {
        ...state,
        started: true,
      };
    case 'result':
      if (!state.pending) return state; // to bail out just in case
      return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        result: action.result,
      };
    case 'error':
      if (!state.pending) return state; // to bail out just in case
      return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error(`unexpected action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

export const useAsyncTask = (func) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    let dispatchSafe = action => dispatch(action);
    let abortController = null;
    const start = async () => {
      if (abortController) return;
      abortController = new AbortController();
      dispatchSafe({ type: 'start' });
      try {
        const result = await func(abortController);
        dispatchSafe({ type: 'result', result });
      } catch (e) {
        dispatchSafe({ type: 'error', error: e });
      }
    };
    const abort = () => {
      if (abortController) {
        abortController.abort();
      }
    };
    dispatch({ type: 'ready', start, abort });
    const cleanup = () => {
      dispatchSafe = () => null; // avoid to dispatch after stopped
      dispatch({ type: 'init' });
    };
    return cleanup;
  }, [func]);
  return state;
};
```

I really like that it has all the loading and error states returned but I cannot use this in an event handler.

Are there any options to use this in an event handler or how else can I get my loading and error states generically?

The README to the package I got the code from gives this example:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

import {
  useAsyncCombineSeq,
  useAsyncRun,
  useAsyncTaskDelay,
  useAsyncTaskFetch,
} from 'react-hooks-async';

const Err = ({ error }) => <div>Error: {error.name} {error.message}</div>;

const Loading = ({ abort }) => <div>Loading...<button onClick={abort}>Abort</button></div>;

const GitHubSearch = ({ query }) => {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}`;
  const delayTask = useAsyncTaskDelay(useCallback(() => 500, [query]));
  const fetchTask = useAsyncTaskFetch(url);
  const combinedTask = useAsyncCombineSeq(delayTask, fetchTask);
  useAsyncRun(combinedTask);
  if (delayTask.pending) return <div>Waiting...</div>;
  if (fetchTask.error) return <Err error={fetchTask.error} />;
  if (fetchTask.pending) return <Loading abort={fetchTask.abort} />;
  if (!fetchTask.result) return <div>No result</div>;
  return (
    <ul>
      {fetchTask.result.items.map(({ id, name, html_url }) => (
        <li key={id}><a target="_blank" href={html_url}>{name}</a></li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      Query:
      <input value={query} onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      {query && <GitHubSearch query={query} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This seems very inefficient, is there a better way?

Comment: I cannot find where is your event handler. You should normally be able to use the  `dispatch` method in en event handler without any problem.

Comment: you won't be able to call this from an event handler because Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.